# How to make network faster by using both cable and wifi

Tags: windows, macos, networking

Is it possible to speed up network file copies by enabling multiple networks? I just enabled WiFi in addition to my cabled network, but the transfer time didn't drop...

Comment: In other words, you're trying to double (or so) the throughput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is [link aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation), and I'm fairly sure it can't be done between wired and wireless connections.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a home network, then probably no, because your wifi by itself is probably faster than your DSL, cable or FIoS connection.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to copy files from where to where? If the file is on the Internet, no amount of speeding up your local network will be significant because the bottleneck is your upstream connection to the ISP. If the file is local, link aggregation as mentioned by John T might work, but you'd need better-than-cheap-consumer grade equipment, especially your router.

I would suggest that you write a more detailed question and post it as new, rather than editing this one.  The hints at ESR's [smart questions](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) essay would probably help.